# 404 after moving site from linux/apache to windows2008/iis7

Tags: php, apache, iis-7, migration

Afrter moving site from RedHAT/CloudLinux/ Apache 2.2 to to Windows 2008 R* / IIS7 got a 404 error : 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This is only .php files but images (png and gif) open correct. Can't test html because use it only loke view and have not permission to create and test dummy html.

Please help.

Comment: Do any page links use absolute paths instead of relative paths? Checked all IIS configuration and permissions?

Comment: No. (( I realy not work with IIS . And I don't know where config files and other. I try to change C:/System32/intsrv/config/AplicatoionHost - but I haven't permission for this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in IIS (I can't remember where) you specify how each file type (by extension) is handled.  The fact that it is only the .php files that are 404ing is the clue - see how IIS has been configured to treat .php files.